# Weird issue on: 413 Request Entity Too Large?

Tags: c#, file-upload

I'm trying to use the custom C# library below for uploading the files.

Http-Multipart-Data-Parser
https://github.com/Vodurden/Http-Multipart-Data-Parser

but I encountered an error: **413 Request Entity Too Large**

I have searching Google for the whole day but still can't resolve the issue. I'm still getting the same error.

If I'm using a sile FileUpload control, I can upload large files without problems.

In my web.config, I have:

```
<system.web>
    <httpRuntime executionTimeout="9999" maxRequestLength="419430400" />
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
  </system.web>
```

Any idea how to resolve this? or using other components to upload large files?

I'm using IIS 10.0 with VS 2010, tks

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer myself by doing the following settings:

1) Adding something similar below in web.config:

```
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <webHttpBinding>
        <binding
          maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647"
          maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"
          maxBufferSize="2147483647" transferMode="Streamed">
        </binding>
      </webHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
 </system.serviceModel>
```

2) in IIS, update the settings of:

- Go to the site, file the Configuration Editor under “Management”
- Go to Sections in

  - system.webServer/security/authentication/anonymousAuthentication
  - system.webServer/security/authentication/windowsAuthentication
- Select From: ApplicationHost.config ’ />
- Unlock the Section

> One thing to mention is that the setting of maxRequestLength seems no
>   longer needed in web.config.